# How can I write a sentence in BNF?

Tags: notation, bnf, ebnf

What is the syntax for writing a sentence in BNF? The structure or correctness of it doesn't matter. I only care whether it has 1 or more words, which may or may not be separated by spaces, and which may or may not contain symbols or numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the syntax for writing a sentence in BNF?

Backus-Naur form (BNF) isn't a data format like JSON or PDF, it's a description of the grammar that defines a given format. You wouldn't write a sentence in BNF, bu you might use BNF to describe what a sentence *is*. That description would probably enumerate the characters acceptable in a sentence, tell you that words are made up up non-whitespace characters, and that sentences are sequences of words separated by spaces and ending with a sentence-terminating punctuation mark. Of course, there are many rules about what makes a valid sentence in a natural language like English, so if you were going down that route you'd probably also need to create entities for things like `subject-phrase`, `verb-phrase`, `object-phrase`, etc.

A complete English grammar expressed in BNF would surely be exceedingly complex. BNF is better suited to grammars of computer languages and formats. You might have a BNF description of JSON, for example, or of allowable syntax in C or Java.

> I only care whether it has 1 or more words, which may or may not be separated by spaces, and which may or may not contain symbols or numbers.

The rules for BNF are available on [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backus%E2%80%93Naur_form) among other places. Again, you wouldn't write a specific sentence with BNF, but you'd say what's allowable for a sentence. So you might have rules like:

```
<char> ::= "A" | "B" | "C" | "D" ...
<word> ::= <char>*
<terminator> ::= "." | "!" | "?"
<phrase> ::= <word> | <word> " " <phrase>
<sentence> ::= <phrase> <terminator>
```

Each rule is built up from other rules, or sometimes built recursively... e.g. the rule for `phrase` says that a phrase is a word or a word plus a space plus a phrase, so you could have any number of space-separated words.

Comment: Thank you Caleb.